# How to "customize" my elements in a matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, element

I wanna build an nxm matrix, n< m, and i want each element Mij = i^j
Any ideas? I tried multiplying various vectors etc but i never get the correct result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n <- 3
m <- 4
outer(seq_len(n), seq_len(m), "^")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    4    8   16
#[3,]    3    9   27   81
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sapply`:

```
t(sapply(1:n, `^`, 1:m))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    4    8   16
#[3,]    3    9   27   81
```

Or even faster:

```
matrix(1:n, ncol=m, nrow=n)^matrix(1:m, ncol=m, nrow=n, byrow=T)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    4    8   16
#[3,]    3    9   27   81
```